How to set up the tailwind.config.js file in Shiny for customization styles
I want to use Tailwind Css in my Shiny app, but I need to customize styles for the project, I read that I need to define tailwind.config = {} as a JSON object. I have done it, but custom classes still don't work. However, pre-defined tailwind classes work normal.


I tried also to do it manually, but still the same result, custom classes from "tailwindConfig.js" don't implement
tags$head(
    tags$link(
      rel = "stylesheet",
      href = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss@2.2.19/dist/tailwind.min.css"
    ),
    tags$script(src = "www/tailwindConfig.js"),
    tags$link(
      rel = "stylesheet",
      href = "custom.css"
    )
  )


Appsilon has a tutorial with this: https://www.appsilon.com/post/how-to-use-tailwindcss-in-shiny
